# Making a button content change within user control on click

Tags: wpf, button, user-controls

I realise that WPF is still a bucket of magic to me. The problem seems to be simple. I have a user control with a button. I would like to change the button content (text) on click.

If I open the form with user control without initialising the button value and then say in

```
void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{ 
    Button.Content = "New Value"; 
}
```

it works.

If I initialise the button value dynamically in the control constructor by `Button.Content = "Init Value"`, the second bit `Button.Content = "New Value"`
never happens (it happens, but button text does not show the change ever again, at least that what it seems).

So I decided to use a binding. Declared `ButtonText` property in MyUserControl (+ the corresponding DependencyProperty with getter and setter) and tried to do `ButtonText = "Init Value";` in constructor and `ButtonText = "New Value";` in `Button_Click()`. The first one works, the second one still does not. I assume because of the wrong data context in `Button_Click()`?

In MyUserControl I tried a few things including

```
<Button x:Name="Button" 
 Content="{Binding Path=ButtonText, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"
 Click="Button_Click" />

<Button x:Name="Button"
 Content="{Binding Path=ButtonText, Element=MyUserControl}" 
 Click="Button_Click" />
```

and nothing seems to work.

What is the easiest way to achieve what I need, i.e. both dynamic initialisation and dynamic change? With an explanation, if possible, please, why my first (direct) approach does not work and what the binding approach is missing.

Thanks a lot!

**EDIT:**

An alternative would be to use triggers.

This example works:

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Content" Value="Init Value"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsClicked" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Content" Value="New Value" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

My problem is that I need a DataTrigger, like this

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Content" Value="Init Value"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=MyUserControlProperty, ElementName=MyUserControl}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Content" Value="New Value" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

How do I make MyUserControlProperty value change propagate properly?

The funniest thing is if I open the control as a new form the initialisation of `Button.Content = "Init Value"` does not screw things up and everything just works. What the? Why is this simple task so hard and why so many behaviours?

Comment: Hard to tell where you went wrong without seeing all the relevant code parts of your UserControl. You may have confused the element names in the UserControl. Changing a Button's Content by a Click handler *always* works when you write it like this: `((Button)sender).Content = "New Value";`

Answer (score -1):

Don't set Button.Content directly, when you have a binding set on it. If you set Button.Content in the Constructor you effectively remove the binding.
This works:

```
<Window x:Class="StackOverflow.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Content="{Binding Path=ButtonText1, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"  Click="Button1_OnClick"></Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

```
using System.Windows;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ButtonText1 = "Paul";
        }

        private void Button1_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ButtonText1 = "Maria";
        }

        public string ButtonText1
        {
            get => (string)GetValue(ButtonText1Property);
            set => SetValue(ButtonText1Property, value);
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ButtonText1.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ButtonText1Property =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ButtonText1", typeof(string), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata("Peter"));


    }
}
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. It is perfectly valid to set a Button's Content directly.

Comment: [Clemens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1136211/clemens) of course is right. My first answer was too rudimentary...

Comment: What you have right now obviously also works. However, according to what OP writes in their question, this is exactly what they tried. According to the question they did not set the Content directly when they also had established a Binding. These were just two different trials. As noted in my comment on the question, it can't be answered without seeing more details.

Comment: Edited again... In any case OP set Button.Content directly in the constructor. This killed the binding.

Comment: OP clearly writes that their attempts to directly set the Content failed when there was no Binding. With a Binding, they did not directly set Content, but the source property (`ButtonText = "New Value";`). You shouldn't desperately try to answer a question that isn't currently answerable.